# RISC-V execution model

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu, risc-v

I'm reading a text book on CPU architecture and I have something that confuses me: The text book defines 4 different instruction execution models in CPUs, Stack (where a CPU only has a stack and is able to perform operations on the first and second elements of the stack and push the result back), Accumulator (the CPU loads a value from the memory and add it to the current accumulated value), Register-Memory (where a CPU has a regiser and performs operations on values from both the memory and the register), Register-register (where a CPU performs operations on values that are only stored in the register). Each execution model has a different format of instructions, my question is, which of these models is used by the RISC-V architecture? because it seems to be, when looking at the RISC-V ISA, that it does all of the above.

Answer (score 3):

In the terminology that you're using, RISC-V is a register-register ISA.

For integer and floating point instructions:

- All arithmetic and logic operations take registers as operands and write the result to a register.
- The only operations that access memory are load and store operations.
- There is no dedicated accumulator register.
- There is no dedicated stack pointer register. The ABI might specify one, but the hardware does not.

While they are not all requirements, together they imply a register-register ISA.

There is one main exception: The RISC-V "A" extension supports atomic read/modify/write memory operations (e.g. atomic swap, atomic add, etc).